# Computing $\mathrm{lcm}(2,3,6)$

Tags: least-common-multiple

I have the following question:

> I will earn money if I share it with 2, 3 and 6 people. The money I am about to earn is less than $100,000 (USD). How much money will I earn if the condition is met?

I know that the possible results are $12, 42, 84$, but I can't find out why.

I am doing:

> 2 x 3 x 6

Which, defragmenting:

> 2 x 3 = 6
>
> 6 x 6 = 36

It is a (very) simple calculation, but my brain got stuck on it. I just can't understand *why* the possible solutions can be $12,42$, and/or $84$.

Could someone explain this one for me?

Comment: Did you mean $100,000 USD?

Comment: Yes. But it's just an exemplification.

Comment: What do you mean "just an exemplification"? Your post had $100,00.

Comment: Man, sorry — didn't read well. I was talking about one hundred.

Comment: @induktio Commas are frequently used as decimal places (e.g. in Europe).

Comment: In many parts of the world the separator between the units place and the tenths is a comma, not a period.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Thanks for letting me know. That makes a lot more sense now (feel kind of dumb for finding that out just now...stupid Americans!).

Comment: Oh guys, sorry for that — didn't know it could cause a mess.

Comment: Presumably you need to distribute the earnings in whole dollars. Otherwise there are many solutions.  Do you get a share?

Comment: It would have been good to link to the page you found this on. Bill Dubuque did provide the link.  I think the problem is badly stated.  If you don't take a share, any multiple of $6$ is a solution.  If you take a share but not an equal one, any number greater than $6$ is an answer.  If you take an equal share, only $84$ is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The LCM of $2,3,6$ is $6$, which you can verify easily.  But presumably you will take a share, too, so we want the LCM of $3,4,7$.  Now there is only one solution less than $100$.

Comment: The LCM of 2, 3 and 6 is 6? Could I divide 2 and 3 per 6? I'm studying through [this source](http://www.basic-mathematics.com/number-theory.html). Yes, very basics. And why do we want the LCM of 3, 4 and 7? It isn't clear enough for me. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: You can divide all of $2,3,6$ into $6$, and not into any smaller number. That is the definition of LCM.  I glanced at the page you linked to, and clicked through to http://www.basic-mathematics.com/least-common-multiple.html and was not impressed.  Although the technique will work, it is not efficient.  For two numbers $a,b$ you have $ab=GCD(a,b)LCM(a,b)$  You can find the GCD using the Euclidean algorithm and then one divide gets the LCM.

Comment: The reason you want the LCM of $3,4,7$ is that you are sharing with $2,3,6$ people, so the total number of people is $3,4,7$ including you.

Comment: @Ross If you read the link you'll see that the intended solutions are multiples of $6$ below $100$ (so "people" includes him). It's poorly posed.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I am guessing that it is a multiple choice problem and that the setter was clever enough to make all the choices be multiples of $6$.  I don't think all three are intended solutions.

Comment: @Ross Ah, that is another way to interpret it I suppose. I too am not impressed by the source.

Comment: I think @BillDubuque is right. 3, 4 and 7 sounds strange to me because the question doesn't includes me. Basically, I will just earn the money if I share it with 2, 3 and 6 people. Reading out loud, I can see your point of view, but I think the purpose of the question is a little different. Anyway, writing down the calculations in a paper clarified a little more your explanation — it makes more sense now.

Comment: Furthermore, the question purposed three different solutions which are those I mentioned in the main question. Can't see how your solution matches them. Can you see my misunderstanding?

Comment: @Ross Hmm, did you see "All you have to do is to make sure that the number is divisible by 2, 3, and 6 at the same time"?

Comment: @BillDubuque: no, and checking the edit history I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @Ross It's in the linked *source*.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge:  I can see how $12$ works if you don't take a share, but then any multiple of $6$ would work the same.  I don't understand $42$ at all.  $84$ works if you get a share equal to the $2,3,6$ other people, which was the point of my hint.  I think that is the answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I am not finding a linked *source*.  Maybe Chrome lost the link.

Comment: @Ross It's in his first comment to you, namely [this source.](http://www.basic-mathematics.com/number-theory.html)

Comment: @BillDubuque:  OK I see it.  I think the problem and proposed solutions are badly stated.  If share is not equal, it is not enough of a constraint to solve the problem.  The son could give any amount to the others and keep the rest.  If it is equal (including the son) my answer holds and $84$ is the only solution.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it's poorly stated, but that remark makes it clear that the intent is as I said above.